# Match parent array with child Array Seeds Ruby on Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

Im creating a seed test on my ruby on rails app, and I got the following arrays:

**Seed.rb file**

```
        company = ["Tecnics"]

        departments = ["hr"],["sales"],["IT"],["marketing"]

        assignments = ["goverment"],["contracts"],["banks"],["servers"]["social media"], ["telecom"]

        country_servers = ["mexico"], ["canada"], ["ohio"], ["New york"]


      company = Division.create!({
       name: company[0]
      })

      #departments
      departments.each { |dept_name, idx|
        dept_names = Division.create!({
          name: dept,
          parent_id: company.id
        })
      }  

      #assignments
      assignments.each  {|assign_name, idx|
        @assign_tmp = Division.create!({
          name: assign_name,
          parent_id: dept_names.id
        })
      }  

     #country_servers
      country_servers.each  {|server_name, idx|
        @server_tmp = Division.create!({
          name: server_name,
          parent_id: assign_tmp.id
        })
      }
File.sort_tree
```

[image]

Lets say I want to match Canada server with sales department. How can I approach this doing it with arrays when I create my seeds? Or How can I match Department with its appropiate assignment and server country in my seeds file?

Do I need to access an array?

I will appreatiate the help!

NOTE: I added my fill seed file

Comment: For "matching" you need another array which will keep matched pairs

Comment: mmmm, ok. but when creating the seeds how will I do that?

Comment: What you mean by "seeds"?

Comment: when I do my **create** function. Iwant that when I type my rails console, I want to see thier respective child's and parent arrays.

Comment: So, you are working in your `seeds.rb` file and are trying to figure out the logic of how to  create and associate records based off of arrays? If this is the case, i'd be helpful to see your current seeds.rb file as well as your schema.

Comment: @MarkMerritt I added my seed file! Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us what the `Division` model looks like?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what the `Division` model looks like, you should be able to generate all of the objects you want by specifying the relationships with arrays of hashes. Something like:

```rb
company = {
  name: 'Tecnics',
  departments: ['HR', 'Sales', 'IT', 'Marketing'],
  assignments: ['Government', 'Telecom']
}

departments = [
  {name: 'HR', parent_name: 'Tecnics', parent_type: 'Company', assignments: ['Contracts']},
  {name: 'Sales', parent_name: 'Tecnics', parent_type: 'Company', assignments: ['Banks'], server: 'Canada'},
  {name: 'IT', parent_name: 'Tecnics', parent_type: 'Company' assignments: ['Severs']},
  {name: 'Marketing', parent_name: 'Tecnics', parent_type: 'Company', assignments: ['Social Media']}
]

assignments = [
  {name: 'Government', parent_name: 'Tecnics', parent_type: 'Company'},
  {name: 'Contracts', parent_name: 'HR', parent_type: 'department' server: 'New York'},
  {name: 'Banks', parent_name: 'Sales', parent_type: 'department'},
  {name: 'Servers', parent_name: 'IT', parent_type: 'department', server: 'Ohio'},
  {name: 'Social Media', parent_name: 'Marketing', parent_type: 'department', server: 'Mexico'},
  {name: 'Telecom' parent_name: 'Tecnics', parent_type: 'Company'}
]

servers = [
  {name: 'Mexico', parent_name: 'Social Media', parent_type: 'assignment'},
  {name: 'Canada', parent_name: 'Sales', parent_type: 'department'},
  {name: 'Ohio', parent_name: 'Servers', parent_type: 'assignment'},
  {name: 'New York', parent_name: 'Contracts', parent_type: 'assignment'}
]
```